# How do I use fullcalendar with events loaded through ASMX returning json

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to use a web service to return json data, that is working fine and I can get the correct data in a jason format but when i try to use that data in the "events:" section nothing happens.

This is my code and I get back what looks like a very good json response but nothing happens, I must be doing something wrong but I can't see what it is.

'
$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var datefrom = '2023-04-01';
        var dateto = '2023-04-30';

        alert(datefrom + ' ' + dateto);

        var jsonInput = { datefrom: datefrom, dateto: dateto };

        var data = JSON.stringify(jsonInput);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetCalendarData.asmx/CalendarData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                var evt = response.d;
                alert(evt);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('Error ' + response);
            }
        });

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialDate: '2023-04-01',
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            businessHours: false,
            eventLimit: true,
            eventLimitText: 'more',
            eventLimitClick: 'popover',
            dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: evt
        });

        calendar.render();
    });`
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. You don't gey the events back until after the calendar has already been passed the evt variable.  Too late by then

Comment: Implement via the documented approach instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: having looked at the documented approach i'm not sure i fully understand it, how do you use  'import { req } from 'superagent';' do you use .query({
        start: startdatestring,
        end: enddatestring

Comment: Hi ADyson having looked at the documented approach i'm not sure i fully understand it, how do you use                                                                                                    
 'import { req } from 'superagent';'                                                                                
  how do you use                 
   .query({
        start: info.start.valueOf(),
        end: info.end.valueOf()

Comment: You are not required to use superagent, that's just an example. You are free to carry on using $.ajax instead. The point is the structure of the code - make the AJAX call within the function, and use the provided callback to pass the events back to fullCalendar - this gets round the problem of the HTTP request being asynchronous, because you actively pass the data to the calendar whenever it completes.